# Using StreamWriter not writable

Tags: c#, stream, streamwriter

I have the below subclass for writing a string to a text file in my application:

```
async void Confirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("text.txt"))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("test text");
    }
}
```

The StreamReader subclass executes correctly, however the second subclass throws exception

> 'Stream not writable'.

I thought this was because I used the same file in another stream (reader not writer) in another subclass, however I've verified this isn't the problem by using two different files to test.

What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: Asset/Resource Bundle based files are read-only as all signed files within the application bundles are. If you wish to write it to, you would need to test on app startup if the file exists in a writable location (assumably within a read/write location in your app's sandbox), copy it from your Asset/ResourceBundle if it does not, and then proceed with your writing.

Comment: Right, that makes sense as to the problem, but I don't understand the solution. How can I update the file "text.txt" within my application? Even if I read from Asset and copy to a writable location, I still can't save that new file anywhere and use it later, right? How would I read it later as using as an Asset seem to be the only way to read a file in Android.